# Rails: undefined method `photos_path'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi I'm currently working with nested resources.

routes

```
Pholder::Application.routes.draw do
resources :users do
  resources :albums do
    resources :photos
  end
end
end
```

I have 3 models (users, albums, photos). I've managed to register users and create albums, but am stuck on trying to make the form for photos. On creation of an album, the user is redirected to the albums/show page:

album/show

```
<% if @album.photos.any? %>
yes  pics
<% else %>
no  pics
<% end %>


<%= link_to "Upload new pics!", new_user_album_photo_path(@user, @album) %>
```

as you can see, on the bottom of the page there's a path to new photos, and that's where the issue is. When I click on the link, it gives me an error:

`undefined method`photos_path' for #<#:0x007fb69e167220>`

the error occurs on line #3 of that page (photos/new)

photos/new

```
<% provide(:title, "Upload pictures") %>

<%= form_for(@photo, :html => { :multipart => true }) do |f| %>

<%= f.file_field :photo %>

<% end %>
```

I suspect that I'm putting the wrong information to the controller (I'm still very shaky on what to put in the controller.)? Here's my photos controller.

photos controller

```
class PhotosController < ApplicationController

    def new
      @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
      @album = @user.albums.find(params[:album_id])
      @photo = @album.photos.build
    end

    def create
      @album = Album.find(params[:album_id])
      @photo = @album.photos.build(params[:photo])
      respond_to do |format|
        if @album.save
          format.html { redirect_to @album, notice: 'Album was successfully created.' }
          format.json { render json: @album, status: :created, location: @album}
        else
          format.html { render action: "new" }
          format.json { render json: @album.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
    end

    def show
      @album = Album.find(params[:album_id])
      @photos = @album.photos
    end


end
```

Is my form incorrect? It's confusing to me what to put in the controller and whether the error is occurring in the form or the controller. Thanks

let me know if you need any more info.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The same way you have to provide parent resources to the `link_to` helper, you also have to supply it to the form. So change the form line to this:

```
 <%= form_for([@user, @album, @photo], :html => { :multipart => true }) do |f| %>
```

.. and it should work!

Comment: perfect!!! thanks a lot. so for nested resources, when you create forms you have to make the form for the parent(?) resources + the resource you are targeting?

Answer (score 2):

So what's happening here is Rails is using a bit of reflection looking at the object you passed to the form helper, which (I'm guessing) is simply a Photo object. Rails, by default, will look for **photos_path** as that is where the POST request will typically go for the **create** action. So it's posting to **/photos** which, unfortunately doesn't exist based on your current routes.

If you change that form helper line to:

```
<%= form_for [@user,@album,@photo], html: { multipart: true} do |f| %>
```

Which causes it to post to **/users/(user id)/albums/(album id)/photos** which should create the new photo.